# Добавление и удаление - код дублируется C#

Tags: c#

Не принимают работу. Помогите решить.

```
static void Add(ref string[] fio, ref string[] position)
    {
        string[] tempFio = new string[fio.Length + 1];
        string[] tempPosition = new string[position.Length + 1];

        Console.WriteLine("Введите ФИО: ");
        string enterFio = Console.ReadLine();
        tempFio[tempFio.Length - 1] = enterFio;

        Console.WriteLine("Введите должность: ");
        string enterPosition = Console.ReadLine();
        tempPosition[tempPosition.Length - 1] = enterPosition;

        for (int i = 0; i < fio.Length; i++)
        {
            tempFio[i] = fio[i];
            tempPosition[i] = position[i];
        }
        fio = tempFio;
        position = tempPosition;
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void Remove(ref string[] fio, ref string[] position)
    {
        string[] tempRemoveFio = new string[fio.Length - 1];
        string[] tempRemovePosition = new string[position.Length - 1];
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();
        if (tempRemoveFio.Length >= id)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tempRemoveFio.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i < id)
                {
                    tempRemoveFio[i] = fio[i];
                    tempRemovePosition[i] = position[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    tempRemoveFio[i] = fio[i + 1];
                    tempRemovePosition[i] = position[i + 1];
                }
            }
            fio = tempRemoveFio;
            position = tempRemovePosition;
            Console.WriteLine($"Вы удалили досье под номером - {id}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Досье под номером {id} не существует.");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: вынесите одинаковый код еще в одну функцию, да и делов

Comment: напишите класс полностью...какие-то странные функции у вас

Comment: Интересно, кто минусы на вопрос навешивает? Вы бы хоть комментарии какие-нибудь оставляли.

Comment: Видимо у вас не только в этих 2-х методах идет создание временных массивов и похожая работа с ними. Надо выносить это в отдельный метод, да и работу с интерфейсом все эти `Console.WriteLine("Введите должность: ");` и `string enterFio = Console.ReadLine();`тоже нужно в отдельный(е) метод(ы). Т.е. мух от котлет отделять нужно: работа с пользователем в одни методы, а работу с массивами в другие методы.

Comment: там примитивно все должно быть. Это начало обучения функций и одно из заданий,написать функцию заполнения массивов – досье,и функцию удаления досье.

Comment: Раз не приняли работу, значит не все должно быть примитивным...